# Непонятный вывод Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Eсть две таблицы:

```
CREATE TABLE admin_ad.event (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  cid varchar(255) NOT NULL COMMENT 'click_id',
  c_id int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'campaign_id',
  date date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
ENGINE = INNODB,
AUTO_INCREMENT = 32272,
AVG_ROW_LENGTH = 50,
CHARACTER SET utf8,
COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

и

```
CREATE TABLE admin_ad.postback (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  c_id varchar(255) NOT NULL COMMENT 'click_id',
  cid int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'campaign_id',
  u_id int(11) NOT NULL,
  date date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
ENGINE = INNODB,
AUTO_INCREMENT = 17,
AVG_ROW_LENGTH = 3276,
CHARACTER SET utf8,
COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

В первой хранится чуть больше 30к записей, а во второй - всего 1.

Пишу вот такой запрос:

```
SELECT
   e.date AS date,
   COUNT(e.cid) AS count,
   COUNT(p.cid) AS count_postback
FROM
   event e 
   LEFT JOIN 
      postback p
      ON p.cid = e.c_id 
WHERE
   e.c_id = '44' 
   AND DATE(e.date) BETWEEN '2020-06-29' AND '2020-07-01' 
GROUP BY
   e.date
```

И ожидаю, что мне выведется вот такое:

```
date        count    count_postback
2020-06-29  3        0
2020-06-30  623      0
2020-07-01  653      1
```

А выводится вот такое:

```
date        count    count_postback
2020-06-29  3        3
2020-06-30  623      623
2020-07-01  653      653
```

Вопрос заключается в том, откуда (и почему?) в `count_postback` выводятся такие же значение, как и в `count`, хотя в таблице `postback` всего одна запись?

Версия сервера: MySQL 5.7.28

**INSERT INTO**

Пока пытаюсь сделать всё на sqlfiddle.com, добавлю сюда

Postback:

```
INSERT INTO postback (id, c_id, cid, u_id, date) VALUES (NULL, 12, 44, '2020-07-01');
```

Event:

```
INSERT INTO event (id, cid, c_id, date) VALUES (NULL, 44, '135224', '2020-06-29');
INSERT INTO event (id, cid, c_id, date) VALUES (NULL, 44, '135748', '2020-06-29');
INSERT INTO event (id, cid, c_id, date) VALUES (NULL, 44, '135487', '2020-06-30');
INSERT INTO event (id, cid, c_id, date) VALUES (NULL, 44, '135284', '2020-06-30');
INSERT INTO event (id, cid, c_id, date) VALUES (NULL, 44, '135997', '2020-07-01');
```

Comment: Добавьте в текст вопроса INSERT INTO с данными (1 запись для postback и 5-6 штук для 2-3 дат в event). Ещё лучше - создайте online fiddle и дайте ссылку.

Comment: @Akina добавил в вопрос, пока не получается добавить на sqlfiddle

Comment: Приведенные данные не соответствуют структуре и запросу. В postback вставляется меньше данных, чем колонок. значение 44 в поле cid а не c_id. И если как то поправить данные руками, то запись postback у меня все равно клеится ко всем записям event. А что до count() то думаю вам надо считать `count(distinct p.id)` например

Comment: @Mike, спасибо, заработало!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если данные в вопросе совпадают с реальными данными, то запрос работает абсолютно корректно, т.к. в таблице `event` есть 5 записей с `id=44` и все они соединяются с одной записью в таблице `postback`

Для того, чтобы увидеть это - сделайте запрос ниже:

```
SELECT *
FROM
   event e 
   LEFT JOIN 
      postback p
      ON p.cid = e.cid 
WHERE
   e.cid = '44' 
   AND DATE(e.date) BETWEEN '2020-06-29' AND '2020-07-01'
```

В результате вы получите таблицу ниже, где нет `Null` значений, т.к. все записи удалось соединить

```
id  cid     c_id    date        id  c_id   cid u_id     date
32272   44  135224  2020-06-29  17  12     44   44  2020-07-01
32273   44  135748  2020-06-29  17  12     44   44  2020-07-01
32274   44  135487  2020-06-30  17  12     44   44  2020-07-01
32275   44  135284  2020-06-30  17  12     44   44  2020-07-01
32276   44  135997  2020-07-01  17  12     44   44  2020-07-01
```

П.С. Чтобы запрос заработал как вам нужно - используйте `COUNT(distinct p.cid)`

Comment: Да! Вы совершенно правы, сделал так же, немного поменял запрос и теперь если группировать так же по дате, то выводятся нули там,где ничего нет, но там, где есть хотя бы одна запись, `count_postback` так же дублируется c `count`. Можете подсказать как это исправить?

Comment: Использовал, distinct и всё заработало

Comment: решение уже указал Mike в комментарии - использовать ```COUNT(distinct p.cid)```